# Laravel to call a function asynchronously

Tags: php, laravel

I need to call a function in laravel controller as asynchronous like the controller doesn't have to wait for that function to execute.

Any idea

Laravel with IIS

Comment: How would you do it outside of a Laravel context?

Comment: You need to use Queues if you want to achieve something Asynch in Laravel

Comment: If you mean async that you want to do something when it's finished in the same context. like multi-threading You just can't. PHP doesn't support multi-threading in any way.

Comment: I am stuck with IIS as IIS i can not use pthread as it required PHP TS and IIS Need NTS

Comment: Any idea to do it by curl or symfony process component to call a manual php function

Comment: Did my answer help your problem? Else i'm glad to try to fix it :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup a queue and make a job. In your controller you would call it like so.

```
pulbic function store()
{
    dispatch(new YourJob());
}
```

To make the job.

```
class YourJob implements implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->yourAsyncCode();
    }
}
```

Setting up the queue is not so straight forward, when you are on ISS i would guess the easiest driver is database. Set your queue driver to the database in your `.env` file.

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Create the tables for the database.

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan migrate
```

Now you have to have a process that is alive at all time that keeps working on the jobs. I don't know how to do it in `IIS`, normally you would do it with the supervisor in ubuntu. There must be some equivalent.

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Comment: This is a very simple answer to a very complex part of Laravel, it takes time and trial and error to set this up. But this is the way to run things async in Laravel.